# EF Core: How can i Select (Distinct) after join?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Basically i want this as query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.description FROM students s
join courses c on s.courseId = c.Id
WHERE c.Id = 100
```

How do i do this in EF Core?
When i do :

```
db.Students
.Include(s => s.courseId)
.Select( -- how can i select for course description? --)
.Distinct()
```

Bear with me. I am new to Entity Framework.

Comment: Please show the relevant classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your Include expression handles the joining for you, so you don't have to specify how your going to  join the table. So your include  will look like this:

```
_db.Students.Include(s => s.Course)
```

Then you'd accomplish your select through the use of a lamba expression like this:

```
_db.Students .Include(s => s.Course).Select(s => s.Course.Description).Distinct()
```